# C++ Error with adding person information inside structure

Tags: c++, struct

I was working on making structure in C++ but it shows error when I try to add new person inside of structure. It just shows this line of error:
`main.cpp:14:42: error: could not convert '{"Marko", 27}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'Person'`

Can you please tell me what I did wrong here?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Person {
    char name[50];
    int age;
    Person* next;
};


int main()
{
    Person* per1 = new Person({"Marko", 27});
    cout << per1 << endl;
}
```

Comment: `new Person({"Marko", 27})` --> `new Person{"Marko", 27}`. Initialization in C++ is hard

Comment: It seems your compiler choice is wrong. Your code [compiles in clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BCWA0FLOXSydW55s) but not compiles in gcc.

Comment: @MikeCAT - Or it's *right* since it points the OP at writing more portable code.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica It won't make much difference. (I got almost same result from gcc and clang)

Comment: Your compiler definitely says more than "error: could not convert".

Comment: This is what it say @molbdnilo main.cpp:14:42: error: could not convert '{"Marko", 27}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'Person'

Comment: @SomeOne 'more than', not 'different than'. Always post complete error messages, there is useful information in the whole error message

Comment: Seems to be https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=90926 - your code indeed compiles on GCC trunk.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I tried compiling it on online GCC compiler but it shows the same error. Idk what to do.

Comment: Note that you leak one `Person` since you don't `delete per1;`.

Comment: @SomeOne - If you are constrained to use GCC (that doesn't contain the bug-fix), then you'll have to work around the problem. If you don't mind that `Person` stops being an aggregate, you can add a constructor. If you do mind that, you can add a "named constructor" (a free/static function that returns a `Person` by value after doing initialization).

Answer (score 2):

Update: as per comments, this seems to be a [gcc bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=90926). Expect the correct behavior to be available in GCC 11.

For now, you can work it around with a constructor:

```cpp
    Person(const char* n, int a, Person* p): age(a), next(p) {
        strncpy(name, n, strlen(n));
        name[strlen(n)] = '\0';
    }
```

Additionally, don't forget to `delete` the `new`ly allocated memory:

```cpp
    Person* per1 = new Person{"Marko", 27, nullptr};
    cout << per1->name << endl;
    delete per1;
```

You are also trying to apply `operator<<` to `Person`. In order to "print" `Person`, you need to overload this operator:

```cpp
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Person& p) {
    return out << "Name: " << p.name << ", Age: " << p.age;
}
```

Make sure the definition is outside the struct.

Then in `main` you will use it like this:

```
cout << *per1 << '\n';
```

Notice the dereference of `per1`. Because `per1` is a pointer, and you want to print the data pointed to, not the address of that data.

Altogether, it looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

struct Person {
    char name[50];
    int age;
    Person* next;
    Person(const char* n, int a, Person* p): age(a), next(p) {
        strncpy(name, n, strlen(n));
        name[strlen(n)] = '\0';
    }
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Person& p) {
    return out << "Name: " << p.name << ", Age: " << p.age;
}

int main()
{
    Person* per1 = new Person{"Marko", 27, nullptr};
    cout << *per1 << '\n';
    delete per1;
}
```

Comment: Yes you *can* write it in C++ and expect it to work. We can do that for about 10 years now.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica if you so claim, why doesn't it compile without ctor?

Comment: @AveMilia But it does (from C++11 and forward): https://godbolt.org/z/6cjzb9

Comment: @TedLyngmo the _only_ gcc this compiles on is trunk. I tested all last major releases up until gcc 4.

Comment: Indeed. It's a good thing the GCC folks are aware that they have a bug https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=90926 , and fixed it in trunk. One compiler's misbehavior is no reason to make false claims about the language as a whole.

Comment: Ok, good to know. Since for me this has never ever compiled, I assumed this is not legal C++.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica the bug reporter claims the code to compile in gcc 5.3. If you open the godbolt link posted by Ted in comments above and select gcc 5.3, it still won't compile. Are you sure this is the correct ticket?

Comment: At least `Person per1{"Marko", 27, nullptr};` works as it should from gcc 4.7.1 in C++11 mode. :)

Comment: @AveMilia - Yes. And you should stop taking the behavior of specific compiler installations as gospel. The godbolt backend could very well have some versions share a GCC shared library or what not.